# Find files using regular expressions in Ubuntu

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, grep

I have a task where i have to find different files with conditions that I think require regular expressions.

For example :

Find files that begin with 3 small letters and where the last letter is not an 'i'. I'm searching for the best way to find those files.

i could do

```
ls [a-z][a-z][a-z]*[azertyuopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn]
```

but yeah, that seems a bit of.
Any ideas ?

Comment: your range for "not i" can be `[a-hj-z]`, right? Good luck.

Comment: and how would you say " no vowels " ? [b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]

Comment: that is one way, but there is a negation operator for char classes, so you could do `[^aeiou0-9::punct::]` (if you really just want lower case chars). Actually [`b-d...]` isn't bad, because it lists explicitly what you **do** want to match, and  you don't try to have to guess about what you might be missing with `::punct::` and some other of the "shortcut" terms. There are other `::named-ranges::` but I don't want to have to try and find you a reference ;-)  (I'm recovering from an operation). Good luck.

Comment: Bash allows `^` for negation but the portable, traditional negation operator is `!`

Comment: @tripleee : Thanks for the reminder. I think in the back of my mind `!` was the csh negation, so I try to block those years from my memoyr ;-) . Nice answer! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ ls
abci  ASds  dferasfds  dsfa998  ilkj323  retk232i

$ find -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[a-z]{3}.*[^i]$'
./dferasfds
./dsfa998
./ilkj323
```

- `.*/` is needed to match beginning part of file path
- `[a-z]{3}` three lowercase letters
- `.*` any other characters
- `[^i]$` not ending with `i`

However, this particular case seems possible without regex:

```
$ find -name '[a-z][a-z][a-z]*[!i]'
./dferasfds
./dsfa998
./ilkj323
```

Answer (score 4):

These are globs, not regular expressions.  You don't need regular expressions for this.

```
printf '%s\n' [a-z][a-z][a-z]*[!i] [a-z][a-z][a-hj-z]
```

The second pattern covers file names which are three characters long; it is unclear from your requirements whether these should be included.  (If no matching file exists, the shell will emit a warning message, but that's harmless.)  If not, just use the first pattern.

(I'm using `printf` mainly to illustrate that the shell does the actual work here, and `ls` is not necessary to expand a glob pattern.)

If you really do require regular expressions, `find -regex 'pattern'` is your friend.  By default, `find` will traverse subdirectories; you can avoid this with `-maxdepth 1`.

Maybe also look at Bash's [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for an in-between option.